# Strategies for One-to-Many type of association where "many" side  entries are in millions

Tags: java, mysql, associations, large-data

Giving an analogy: Twitter like scenario where in a person can be followed by huge number of people (one-to-many) ,

Few options which I could think of

1. Use some OR mapping tool with lazy loading. But when you access the "followers" side of relations, it will still load all the data even tough lazily. So not a suitable option.
2. Do not maintain one-to-many relation (or not use any OR mapping) . Fetch the "Followers" side  in separate call and handle the paging etc programmatically.
3. Offload Fetching of large data to some search stack (Lucene/Solr) which can better handle large data. But this will introduce some latency between database update and index update.

Please share your thoughts/suggestions and any possible tools library. Stack consists of Java , MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Millions should not be a problem for an RDBMS as it is designed for those situations.

Sometimes it is also recommended to denormalize rather than normalize to optimize the performance of your application. This is specifically for applications that have very high read and very low write statistics.

Comment: I am worried about the RDBMS. I am more concerned about handling this data on application side.

Comment: As to how to fetch the data: query optimization should help a lot. On the other side: holding millions of records in memory could be a big performance hit for your application server (memory-wise), but you can also optimize this. (lazy loading, paginated loading, etc)