# Is it safe for one ancestor to have millions of children in one List object?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Java and JDO with the Google App Engine datastore.

If I have a @PersistenceCapable class that contains a List of another 
@PersistenceCapable class, and that List is millions of items in size, 
is that OK?

Does that exceed a maximum for Java's List size?

What is the best way for an ancestor to have millions of children and 
still have it easy to add new children without loading tons of data in to 
memory?

Answer (score 1):

Generally the typical parent-child relationship of the available OR-mapping tools is not suited fro these type of scenarios wherein the children are huge in number.

I had [similar scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125301/strategies-for-one-to-many-type-of-association-where-many-side-entries-are-in) and there we removed the mapping part from OR mapping and loaded the children using explicit calls wherever needed.

We could apply various optimizations like fetching only the needed children or fetching them page-wise  etc.